# spring security could not find the data

Tags: mysql, spring, hibernate, spring-security, spring-boot

I am trying to use Spring Security in my project but I can not find the source of mistake. I get the same exception the hole time:

> Not all named parameters have been set: [login] [SELECT DISTINCT u
>   FROM User u LEFT JOIN FETCH u.roles WHERE u.login=:login]

Why can not I send all parameters to server? I use Spring Boot, Hibernate and MySQL.
My project:
login.jsp page:

```
<%@ page contentType="text/html;charset=UTF-8" language="java" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="spring" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags" %>
<%@taglib prefix="form" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form" %>
<%@ page contentType="text/html;charset=UTF-8" language="java" %>
<html>
    <jsp:include page="headTag.jsp"/>
<body>
<div class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                <li>
                    <form:form class="navbar-form" role="form" action="login"
                         method="post">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="login"> Login: </label>
                            <div class="col-sm-3">
                                <input type="text" placeholder="Login" class="form-control" name='login' id="login">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="password"> Password: </label>
                            <div class="col-sm-3">
                                <input type="password" placeholder="Password" class="form-control" name='password' id="password">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                        <button type="submit" class="btn  btn-sm btn-block btn-primary">Sign in</button>
                        </div>
                    </form:form>
                    <br/>
                    <form class="navbar-form" action="{/register}">
                        <button class="btn btn-sm btn-block btn-primary">Register</button>
                    </form>
                </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="jumbotron">
    <div class="container">
        <c:if test="${error}">
            <div class="error">
                    ${sessionScope["SPRING_SECURITY_LAST_EXCEPTION"].message}
            </div>
        </c:if>
        <c:if test="${not empty message}">
            <div class="message">
                <spring:message code="${message}"/>
            </div>
        </c:if>
        <p>
            <br/><br/><br/><br/>
        <p>User login: <b> Bill </b></p>
        <p>User password: <b> 112233 </b></p>

        <p>Стек технологий: <a href="http://projects.spring.io/spring-security/">Spring Security</a>,
            <a href="http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html">Spring MVC</a>,
            <a href="http://projects.spring.io/spring-data-jpa/">Spring Data JPA</a>,
            <a href="http://spring.io/blog/2014/05/07/preview-spring-security-test-method-security">Spring Security
                Test</a>,
            <a href="http://hibernate.org/orm/">Hibernate ORM</a>,
            <a href="http://hibernate.org/validator/">Hibernate Validator</a>,
            <a href="http://www.slf4j.org/">SLF4J</a>,
            <a href="https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson">Json Jackson</a>,
            <a href="http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSP">JSP</a>,
            <a href="http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JavaServer_Pages_Standard_Tag_Library">JSTL</a>,
            <a href="http://tomcat.apache.org/">Apache Tomcat</a>,
            <a href="http://www.webjars.org/">WebJars</a>,
            <a href="http://datatables.net/">DataTables plugin</a>,
            <a href="http://ehcache.org">Ehcache</a>,
            <a href="http://www.postgresql.org/">PostgreSQL</a>,
            <a href="http://junit.org/">JUnit</a>,
            <a href="http://hamcrest.org/JavaHamcrest/">Hamcrest</a>,
            <a href="http://jquery.com/">jQuery</a>,
            <a href="http://ned.im/noty/">jQuery notification</a>,
            <a href="http://getbootstrap.com/">Bootstrap</a>.</p>
    </div>
</div>
<jsp:include page="footer.jsp"/>
</body>
</html>
```

User class:

```
@NamedEntityGraphs({
        @NamedEntityGraph(name = User.GRAPH_WITH_ROLES, attributeNodes = @NamedAttributeNode("roles")),
        @NamedEntityGraph(name = User.GRAPH_WITH_ROLES_AND_CONTACTS, attributeNodes =
                {
                        @NamedAttributeNode("roles"),
                        @NamedAttributeNode("contacts")
                })
})
@NamedQueries({
        @NamedQuery(name = User.DELETE, query = "DELETE FROM User u WHERE u.id=:id"),
        @NamedQuery(name = User.BY_LOGIN, query = "SELECT DISTINCT u FROM User u LEFT JOIN FETCH u.roles WHERE u.login=:login"),
        @NamedQuery(name = User.ALL_SORTED, query = "SELECT DISTINCT u FROM User u LEFT JOIN FETCH u.roles ORDER BY u.login"),
})
@Entity
@Table(name = "users", uniqueConstraints = {@UniqueConstraint(columnNames = "login", name = "users_unique_login_idx")})
public class User extends NamedEntity{

    public static final String GRAPH_WITH_ROLES = "User.WithRoles";
    public static final String GRAPH_WITH_ROLES_AND_CONTACTS = "User.WithRolesAndContacts";
    public static final String DELETE = "User.DELETE";
    public static final String BY_LOGIN = "User.BY_LOGIN";
    public static final String ALL_SORTED = "User.All_SORTED";


    @Column(name = "password", nullable = false)
    @Length(min = 5, max = 100, message = "your password should have 5 or more symbols")
    @JsonView(View.REST.class)
    @NotEmpty
    private String password;

    @Column(name = "full_name", nullable = false)
    @Length(min = 5, max = 100, message = "your fullName should have 5 or more symbols")
    private String fullName;

    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    @CollectionTable(name = "user_roles", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "user_id"))
    @Column(name = "role")
    @ElementCollection(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    protected Set<Role> roles;

    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.REMOVE, fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "user")
    @OrderBy("firstName DESC")
    protected List<Contact> contacts;

    public User() {
    }

    public User(User u) {
        this(u.getId(), u.getLogin(), u.getPassword(), u. getFullName(), u.getRoles());
    }

    public User(Integer id, String login, String password, String fullName, Role role, Role... roles) {
        this(id, login, password, fullName, EnumSet.of(role, roles));
    }

    public User(Integer id, String login, String password, String fullName, Set<Role> roles) {
        super(id, login);
        this.password = password;
        this.fullName = fullName;
        setRoles(roles);
    }

    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }

    public String getFullName() {
        return fullName;
    }

    public void setFullName(String fullName) {
        this.fullName = fullName;
    }

    public Set<Role> getRoles() {
        return roles;
    }

    public void setRoles(Set<Role> roles) {
        this.roles = CollectionUtils.isEmpty(roles) ? Collections.emptySet() : EnumSet.copyOf(roles);
    }
    public List<Contact> getContacts() {
        return contacts;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "User{" +
                "password='" + password + '\'' +
                ", fullName='" + fullName + '\'' +
                ", roles=" + roles +
                '}';
    }
}
```

Contact class:

```
@NamedQueries({
        @NamedQuery(name = Contact.GET, query = "SELECT cont FROM Contact cont WHERE cont.id=:id AND cont.user.id=:userId"),
        @NamedQuery(name = Contact.ALL_SORTED, query = "SELECT cont FROM Contact cont WHERE cont.user.id=:userId ORDER BY cont.firstName DESC"),
        @NamedQuery(name = Contact.DELETE, query = "DELETE FROM Contact cont WHERE cont.id=:id AND cont.user.id=:userId"),
        @NamedQuery(name = Contact.GET_FILTERED, query = "SELECT cont FROM Contact cont WHERE cont.user.id=:userId " +
                "AND cont.firstName LIKE :firstName AND cont.lastName LIKE :lastName " +
                "AND cont.mobilePhone LIKE :mobilePhone ORDER BY cont.firstName DESC"),
})
@Entity
@Table(name = "contacts")
public class Contact extends BaseEntity{

    public static final String GET = "Contact.GET";
    public static final String ALL_SORTED = "Contact.ALL_SORTED";
    public static final String DELETE = "Contact.DELETE";
    public static final String GET_FILTERED = "Contact.GET_FILTERED";
    @Column(name = "first_name", nullable = false)
    @NotEmpty
    @Length(min = 4)
    private String firstName;
    @Column(name = "last_name", nullable = false)
    @NotEmpty
    @Length(min = 4)
    private String lastName;
    @Column(name = "patronymic", nullable = false)
    @NotEmpty
    @Length(min = 4)
    private String patronymic;
    @Column(name = "mobile_phone_number", nullable = false)
    @NotEmpty
    @Pattern(regexp = "\\+380\\([1-9]{2}\\)[0-9]{7}", message = "format should be like +380(66)1234567" +
            "")
    private String mobilePhone;
    @Column(name = "home_phone_number")
    private String homePhone;
    @Column(name = "address")
    private String address;
    @Email
    @Column(name = "email", nullable = false)
    private String email;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "user_id", nullable = false)
    private User user;

    public Contact() {
    }

    public Contact(String firstName, String lastName, String patronymic, String mobilePhone, String homePhone, String address, String email ) {
        this(null,firstName,lastName,patronymic,mobilePhone,homePhone,address,email);
    }

    public Contact( Integer id, String firstName, String lastName, String patronymic, String mobilePhone, String homePhone, String address, String email ) {
        super(id);
        this.firstName = firstName;
        this.lastName = lastName;
        this.patronymic = patronymic;
        this.mobilePhone = mobilePhone;
        this.homePhone = homePhone;
        this.address = address;
        this.email = email;
    }

    public String getFirstName() {
        return firstName;
    }

    public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
    }

    public String getLastName() {
        return lastName;
    }

    public void setLastName(String lastName) {
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }

    public String getPatronymic() {
        return patronymic;
    }

    public void setPatronymic(String patronymic) {
        this.patronymic = patronymic;
    }

    public String getMobilePhone() {
        return mobilePhone;
    }

    public void setMobilePhone(String mobilePhone) {
        this.mobilePhone = mobilePhone;
    }

    public String getHomePhone() {
        return homePhone;
    }

    public void setHomePhone(String homePhone) {
        this.homePhone = homePhone;
    }

    public String getAddress() {
        return address;
    }

    public void setAddress(String address) {
        this.address = address;
    }

    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }

    public User getUser() {
        return user;
    }

    public void setUser(User user) {
        this.user = user;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Contact{" +
                "firstName='" + firstName + '\'' +
                ", lastName='" + lastName + '\'' +
                ", patronymic='" + patronymic + '\'' +
                ", mobilePhone='" + mobilePhone + '\'' +
                ", homePhone='" + homePhone + '\'' +
                ", address='" + address + '\'' +
                ", email='" + email + '\'' +
                '}';
    }
}
```

RootController

```
@Controller
public class RootController extends AbstractContactController {

    @RequestMapping(value = "/", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String root() {
        return "redirect:/login";
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/contacts", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String contactList() {
        return "contacts";
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/login", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String login(ModelMap model,
                        @RequestParam(value = "error", required = false) boolean error,
                        @RequestParam(value = "message", required = false) String message) {

        model.put("error", error);
        model.put("message", message);
        return "login";
    }
}
```

WebSecurityConfiguration file:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .csrf().disable()
                .authorizeRequests()
                    .antMatchers(HttpMethod.OPTIONS, "/**").permitAll()
                    .antMatchers(HttpMethod.GET, "/**").permitAll()
                    .antMatchers(HttpMethod.POST, "/**").permitAll()
                    .antMatchers(HttpMethod.PUT, "/**").permitAll()
                    .antMatchers(HttpMethod.DELETE, "/**").permitAll()
                    .antMatchers("/js/**", "/css/**").permitAll()
                    .anyRequest().authenticated()
                    .and()
                .formLogin()
                    .loginPage("/login")
                    .failureUrl("/login")
                    .permitAll()
                    .and()
                .logout()
                    .permitAll()
                    .logoutUrl("/logout")
                    .logoutSuccessUrl("/login");;

    }
}
```

My Authorized user with DTO:

```
public class AuthorizedUser extends org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    private UserDTO userDTO;

    public AuthorizedUser(User user) {
        super(user.getLogin(), user.getPassword(), true,  true, true, true, user.getRoles());
        this.userDTO = UserUtil.userAsDTO(user);
    }

    public static AuthorizedUser safeGet() {
        Authentication auth = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();
        if (auth == null) {
            return null;
        }
        Object principal = auth.getPrincipal();
        return (principal instanceof AuthorizedUser) ? (AuthorizedUser) principal : null;
    }

    public static AuthorizedUser get() {
        AuthorizedUser user = safeGet();
        requireNonNull(user, "No authorized user found");
        return user;
    }

    public static int id() {
        return get().userDTO.getId();
    }

public void update(UserDTO newDTO) {
    userDTO = newDTO;
}

public UserDTO getUserDTO() {
    return userDTO;
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return userDTO.toString();
}
```

}

Why I get this exception?
Thanks people?

Comment: The error message means, that you didn't give parameter `login` to your query. I cannot see, where you give the parameter to your query. Can you mark this part of your code?

Comment: Yes, you was write. Queries were correct, but I did not give 'login' parameter into my User repository. I fixed it, thanks bro.